# Physical aspects of representations of $C^{*}$ algebras

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantization, deformation-quantization

Suppose I have a $C^{*}$ algebra $\mathcal{A}$ of quantum observables. I could have used deformation quantization to obtain it from the classical Poisson manifold, or I could've just guessed it – for what follows it doesn't matter.

**Is there a recipe for picking up a physically relevant representation $\rho$ of $\mathcal{A}$ (the "Hilbert space")?**

If yes, what is it? I only know of a construction called GNS which assigns representations to $C^{*}$ algebras given a *state* (linear functional) on the algebra. Is GNS always physically relevant? If yes, how do I know which state to use?

If no, is it true that *different* (meaning unitary in-equivalent) choices of $\rho$ lead to different quantum theories with the same classical limit?

Comment: I think this is an extremely difficult problem. It's one of the reasons many people say that deformation quantization is not a quantization procedure. Indeed, it's functorial, while all other known methods of producing both an algebra of observables and a Hilbert space on which they act faithfully and irreducibly require significant choices, with no guarantee that different choices will be equivalent.